# Mysqldump tables from different databases?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I want to backup two tables: **table1** and **table2**.

**table1** is from database **database1**.

**table2** is from database **database2**.

Is there a way to dump them with a single mysqldump call?

I know I can do:

```
mysqldump -S unixSocket --skip-comments --default-character-set=utf8 --databases database1 --tables table1 > /tmp/file.sql
```

But how to dump two tables from different databases?

Comment: don't have a elegant solution, why restricted to single mysqldump call only?

Comment: Do it twice, but second time with `>> /tmp/file.sql` :-).

Comment: @Michał Powaga Will that append to file instead of rewriting?

Comment: @RichardKnop, yes it will append to file if exists or create new one if not exists. [Redirection (computing) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)

Comment: @Michał Powaga Ok, post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `mysqldump` twice but second time with redirect to file as append `>> /tmp/file.sql`.

Comment: You can't use `--databases` with multiple databases in combination with `--tables`.

Answer (score 3):

There are three general ways to invoke *mysqldump*:

> ```
> shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
> shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name ...
> shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
> ```

Only the first one lets you select the database and table name, but doesn't allow multiple databases. If you use the second or third option you'll dump the selected databases (second) or all databases (third).

So, you can do it but you'll need to dump to entire databases.

As Michał Powaga stated in the comments, you might also do it twice.

> first time with "`> /tmp/file.sql`"
>
> second time with "`>> /tmp/file.sql to append`"

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
mysqldump --databases db_name1 [db_name2 ...] > my_databases.sql
```

Check for reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Hope it helps

Comment: this dumps entire database, while the question was to dump only certain tables

Answer (score 2):

This might be a workaround but you could ignore the other tables you DON'T want to backup.

Such as in your case:

```
mysqldump --databases database1 database2 --ignore-table=database1.table2 --ignore-table=database2.table1
```

You need to define each table you DON'T want to dump with each --ignore-table statement.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For linux/bash, oneliner:

`(mysqldump dbname1 --tables table1; mysqldump dbname2 --tables table2) | gzip > dump.sql.gz`